# What's ls option in OS X does what ls -w 1 in Linux does, showing output in one column?

Tags: bash

In Linux `ls -w 1` shows list of files in 1 column instead of multi-column. What flag or other command will produce the same result in OS X?

Current output under OS X:

```
ls: 1: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of the `ls -w 1` command from Linux in OS X is: `ls -1`

From the man page for [`ls`:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html)

> -1 (The numeric digit “one”.) Force output to be one entry per line. This is  the default when output is not to a terminal.